# C# Query on Excel file oledb IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed

Tags: c#, oledb

I get an IErrorInfo error while executing this query in oledb, someone can help me?

```
"Select [Indirizzo] from [Mappatura$] Where [Cliente]='"+ Cliente[0].ToString()+"' AND [Soc]='"+Cliente[1].ToString()+"'"
```

Comment: ierrorinfo.getdescription failed whit E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Access Reversed symbol ("$"), this is causing the problem. Check this link out: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=05072bb5-da4f-40d0-8664-dd50ad5dbb6b&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc272229038

Comment: the query is on an excel file whitout the $ after the sheet name will not work

Comment: Try to add ranges. Check this one: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Excel-file-using-OLEDB-Data-Provider-in-C-Net.aspx

Comment: "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + FileName + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"   this is my connection string and is ok on other querys the problem is on this single query

Comment: What do you mean by pasting the connection string?

Comment: i can't use a range is senseless i need all that datas not a part. i don't need a workaround i need just to understand why i'm getting this error

Comment: can you post your whole call to the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable GetDatas(string QueryString, string SheetName)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + FileName + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(QueryString, MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", SheetName);
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dt = DtSet.Tables[0];

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            return dt;
        }
```